# Custom Delegating Handler specific to a Controller in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I have written a Custom Delegating Handler which add custom headers to the response & checks in the request .

I added the handles in WebAPi configuration

`config.MessageHandlers.Add(new customHandler());`

But the issue is applies to all the controllers. I need to apply custom header specific to a controllers. Is it possible to add custom handlers specific to a controller?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At the end of this article it explains how to apply handlers only to certain routes: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers. You may have to create a unique handler for your controller for it to apply to that controller only.

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "MyCustomHandlerRoute",
        routeTemplate: "api/MyController/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "MyController", id = RouteParameter.Optional },
        constraints: null,
        handler: HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(new HttpControllerDispatcher(config), new MyCustomDelegatingMessageHandlerA());
    );
```

Regarding how the pipeline of per-route message handlers would look like, you can look [**here**](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-46-38-WebApiStackDiagramsNew/6428.ASP.NET_5F00_MVC4_5F00_WebAPI_5F00_StackDiagram_5F00_Future.jpg).

Comment: Thanks for the Link ,its really self explanatory .

Comment: @kiran-challa and Nick, How to have the same working with "Attribute Routing" ? Is it even possible?

Comment: dead link in last sentence

Answer (score 6):

What you can do is use the per-route message handler but be careful here. As the article that @Nick linked in his answer, you can chain the handler and ensure that the `HttpControllerDispatcher` is involved. Otherwise, you won't get into the Controller pipeline.

One other option which I like is to use the `HttpControllerDispatcher` as a base class for your custom handler:

```
public class CustomerOrdersDispatcher : HttpControllerDispatcher {

    public CustomerOrdersDispatcher(HttpConfiguration config) 
        : base(config) {
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken) {

        // Do some stuff here...

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Here, how you will register it:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "CustomerOrdersHttpRoute",
        routeTemplate: "api/customers/{customerKey}/orders/{key}",
        defaults: new { controller = "CustomerOrders", key = RouteParameter.Optional },
        constraints: null,
        handler: new CustomerOrdersDispatcher(config)
    );

    config.MessageHandlers.Add(new SomeOtherHandler1());
    config.MessageHandlers.Add(new SomeOtherHandler2());
}
```

After `SomeOtherHandler1` and `SomeOtherHandler2` are executed, your `CustomerOrdersDispatcher` will be executed for **CustomerOrdersHttpRoute** route. So, you can see that you preserve the default handler behavior and set some global handlers while you have a route specific one as well.

Here is the full implementation of my `CustomerOrdersDispatcher`: https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/AdvancedWebAPI/blob/master/PerRouteMHOwnershipSample/Dispatcher/CustomerOrdersDispatcher.cs.

You may view the full sample application source code as well to see how it works out: https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/AdvancedWebAPI/tree/master/PerRouteMHOwnershipSample